# changing font in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, latex

im trying to render math equations using matplotlib but i can't change the font to Fira Code(Nerd Font).

```py
from matplotlib import mathtext, font_manager
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['savefig.transparent'] = True
mpl.rcParams['text.color'] = "white"

#texFont = font_manager.FontProperties(size=30, fname="./OpenSans-Medium.ttf")
texFont = font_manager.FontProperties(size=30, family='serif', math_fontfamily='cm')

mathtext.math_to_image(
    r"""Sum of zeroes: $\alpha + \beta  $
    Some text""",
    "output.png",
    prop=texFont,
    dpi=300,
    format='png'
)
```

I also get this statement when i run the code

`Font 'default' does not have a glyph for '\n' [U+a], substituting with a dummy symbol.`

how do i fix this?

**output.png**
[image: output.png]

Comment: Your output looks like News Times Roman --> Default setting. Just a guess... is the font Fira Code(Nerd Font) part of your windows system fonts? Might have to add it...

Comment: @sebo1234 i do have fira code installed, i even use it in my windows terminal and vsc